# Display Suite Block Field, missing in transcendent node reference rendered display

Tags: views, nodes, display-suite

i'm having trouble getting this right. any help is much appreciated. thanks.

I have 3 content types:

- A = product
- B = additional attributes for product
- C = retailer of product

content type B and content type C are created from and related to content type A via autocomplete node reference field.

I created a views block of all content type B related to content type A.

I created a display suite block field for the block and added it to the node display of content type A. render as full node.

all good so far.

Now on content type C display; I used the node reference field that is referencing my content type A node, and use render full node. so I have my content type A node as field attribute on my content type C node, but that rendered content type A node reference field does not include the rendered content type B node block field.

I need that content type B ds block field to be a permanent attribute of content type A, so it shows when I render content type A on content type C

should display suite block field work in this case ?

what should my views settings look like (generally) to make the node reference block field transcendent?

what I am missing?

Thank you